# PowerShell Connect Wirless Adapter

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

PowerShell 3.0 has several built-in NetAdapter cmdlets / functions.  Is it possible to connect / disconnect a wireless adapter using this new noun?  For example:

Enable-NetAdapter
or

Set-NetAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to. I successfully disabled my wired adapter with the following command.

```
Get-NetAdapter | Disable-NetAdapter
```

And then I successfully enabled it using:

```
Get-NetAdapter | Enable-NetAdapter
```

I would imagine as long as the Get-NetAdapter cmdlet returns your wireless adapter you will be able to use the Enable\Disable cmdlets.

Comment: Thank you it worked a treat.  Sorry for the delay in replying.